# Action logging in pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

Just like in case of UFT where it logs all actions with timestamp, how do I enable logging for actions that pywinauto performed on the application so that it automatically generates a log? This is specially useful in case of debugging the pywinauto code. Currently i  have used print statement to log to file.

Comment: Did you try `pywinauto.actionlogger.enable()`?

Comment: I had some issues with import ActionLogger. Maybe due to some code that I copied from internet. I got it working now. Thanks for the pointers

Comment: OK, will add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every action should be logged if you have logging config and run the following code before the tests:

```
from pywinauto import actionlogger
actionlogger.enable()
```

If you see some action is not logged, please report a bug on GitHub.

Comment: I want the actionlogger to log its actions into a file. I am using the following code but it is not creating anything in that file. actionLogFile = " c:\testlogs.txt" actionlogger.StandardLogger(logFilePath=actionLogFile) Am I missing anything? I could see the actions being logged on command prompt.

I am also using sys.stdout = open (logFile,'w') in my code to redirect print statement out to another file.

Comment: As a library pywinauto shouldn't care of logging config. An application/script should create proper file handlers for `logging` module. It should be described in standard Python docs. I know usage example would be helpful anyway. But I have no much time for that right now. If you were spent some time to prepare such an example, it would be really great! Thanks! P.S. It's 100% possible.

Comment: [mspaint.py](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/examples/mspaint.py) example shows how to use logging. Some actions may not be logged for "uia". Will inspect all action related methods soon.

Answer (score 0):

from pywinauto import actionlogger

pywinauto.actionlogger.enable()

Thanks to Vasily Ryabov